# why can't we use graphs as an algebraic structure?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

i started to learn graph theory and basic algebra only recently and I'm kind of still learning the subject, lately i encountered with the next material:

$\textbf{for example}$: 
let G be a cyclic group, means $G=<p> , when \ p \in \mathbb{F}$ (some field).
we know that there is a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $G \cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. lets define the graph H=(V,E), V=G , and {v,u}$\in E \iff v\odot u = p^{|G|}$ so first prove that for any n, H is well defined and also prove that for any $g \in $ G , $g^{|G|} =1_G$ using qualities of H.

my question is, if for any basic algebraic structure G (hence - group), and for any statement on G we can build a representative graph H=(V,E) with V = G , so that we can deduce the statement from the given graph?
and if we can ,why don't mathematicians use that to study groups (as far as i know).

Comment: It looks like you're about to reinvent [Cayley graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph). But the particular graph structure you're defining encode only which elements are each other's inverses, not how the group operations work in general.